# Spyder3 Ipython console threading issue

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I was trying to implement an easy threading in python. I got the following code work in Spyder2 but it seems in spyder3, the print of e1 and e2 are printed at the same time. In spyder3, I also tried this code in python console instead of ipython console. It works fine in python console.

Can anyone let me know is this an issue for spyder3 or my configuration is incorrect? If my configuration is incorrect, can anyone help me to change it? Thanks a lot for your help.

```
import threading
def x(e1,e2):
    e1.wait(timeout=2)
    print("e1")
    e2.wait(timeout=2)
    print("e2")

e1 = threading.Event()
e2 = threading.Event()
t = threading.Thread(target=x,args=(e1,e2,))
t.start()
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? This is working fine for me on Linux, using Spyder 3.1.3 and Qtconsole 4.3.

Comment: I am using win 10 platform with anaconda 2.5.0 64 bit.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem in Spyder, but I really can't tell, sorry.

Comment: But anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this issue can be solved by updating the anaconda package and qt package. See this thread for more details. Cheers. [See here for more details](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4362#issuecomment-294385815)